# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un join utilizando la definición de mi relación que está en el modelo de eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

Ahorita armo mi consulta utilizando el QueryBuilder y está bien.

```
$query = MiModelo::query();
$query->join('tablaRelacion', 'mimodelo.id', '=','tablaRelacion.id_mimodelo')

dd($query->toSql());
```

Pero quiero saber cómo puedo utilizar la definición de mi relación, que está en el modelo para generar ese join. Si en el modelo MiModelo tengo una relación "relacion", algo como:

```
$query = MiModelo::with('relacion');

dd($query->toSql());
```

Y me debe generar el mismo sql, alguna sugerencia?, es soportado en laravel 5.6?

Comment: redacta mejor tu pregunta no me queda claro cual es el problema

Comment: @AlfredoPaz Ya la edite pero lo que quiero generar es, un query builder utilizando la definición de mi relación que se encuentra en el modelo. No le veo mucho sentido hacer un join si ya tengo una relación que define dicho join. Es posible?

Comment: Eloquent no va a generar un join, genera una subconsulta a la tabla secundaria con el ID de la tabla principal, el resultado puede ser el mismo pero el query no lo va a ser.